# Fetch data from two diff databases in CI format with cross conditions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->fifo_db->select('u.name,d.title');
$this->fifo_db->from('tbl_user u');
$this->db->join('designations d','d.id = u.designationid','left');
$this->db->where(array('u.designationid > ' => 1,'d.salary > ' => '20000'));
$query = $this->fifo_db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Trying to fetch data in CI format using join on two tables from different DBs, getting error on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prefix the table references with the name of the database.

This code doesn't use Query Builder or table aliases for a couple of reasons.

1. To prove the concept of multiple databases it's easier to write the
   complete query string.
2. I'm not sure how well aliases will work along
   with the db name prefixes, nor do I know how to alias when including the db name.

I check the return of `db->query` because it will be FALSE if the query causes an error. If `$query` is FALSE a call to `$query->result_array()` would cause an exception to be thrown.

You need the actual database names. I've made up the names `dbU` and `dbD`.

```
$sql = "SELECT dbU.tbl_user.name, dbD.designations.title FROM dbU.tbl_user  
        LEFT JOIN dbD.designations ON dbD.designations.id = dbU.tbl_user.designationid
        WHERE dbU.tbl_user.designationid > 1 AND dbD.designations.salary > 20000";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

if($query !== FALSE)
{
    return $query->result_array();
}

return NULL;
```

I don't think it will matter which CI database object (`fifo_db` or `db`) you use. I'm pretty sure the databases need to be on the same network server.

If the above works you can add the aliases and then, if that works, refactor it to use Query Builder. Frankly, I don't see any reason for QB based on the query shown. But you may have more complicated needs you're not sharing.